# Find all solutions to a particular differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Find all solutions on ${R}$ of the differential equation $ y' = 3|y|^ \frac{2}{3} $

I believe I need to use separation of variables, but it will only work if the initial condition is nonzero. Therefore, not all solutions can be found this way.

Answer (score -1):

Observe that: /y/^(2/3) = y^(2/3). So we solve: dy/dx = 3*y^(2/3).

Use separation of variables: y^(-2/3)dy = 3dx.

So: 3*y^(1/3) = 3x + C.

So: y = (x + C)^3 with y(0) = C^3.